# React-Data-table-component two selectors under one column

Tags: reactjs, react-data-table-component

This is the first time using Datatable in ReactJS and in my API I have columns with sub-rows, which I do not know how to do it. And there are no examples available. If anyone can help me out with some advice, I will really appreciate it. Thanks!

This is what I did so far:

```
const columns = [
    {
      name: "Identification",
      selector: row => row.Identification,
    },
    {
      name: "Sequence Number",
      selector: row => row.SequenceNumber,
    },
    {
      name: "Name",
      selector: row => row.Name,
    },
    {
      name: "Type",
      selector: row => row.Type,
    },
    {
      name: "Photo",
      selector: row => <img height="30px" width="30px" alt={row.Identification} src={row.Photo} />
    },
    {
      name: "Customer Segment",
      selector: row => row.CustomerSegment,
      cell: (d) => <span>{d.CustomerSegment.join(", ")}</span>,
    },
    {
      name: "Service and Facility",
      selector: row => row.ServiceAndFacility,
    },
    {
      name: "Accessibility",
      selector: row => row.Accessibility,
    },
    {
      name: "Other Service and Facility",
      selector: row => row.OtherServiceAndFacility,
    },
```

This is how it looks like in the API:
[image: API]